# How do I make C++ save the contents of a variable after it is changed by a cin input?

Tags: c++, string, cin

If I was to declare a string variable and then use a cin user input to save in this variable, how could I make the input (the contents of the variable) save in a txt file, and then every other time the program is run, it saves the input in a different file?

I made the program, with the declaration of the string variable and the cin input to save in the variable, but then I had to stop because I didn't know how to make the variable contents save to a txt file, which is essential for how I intend to use my program. I have searched online but cannot find anything applicable to solving my problem.

Comment: Instead of usin cin directly, use it through some functions which take the input and immediately write it to your text file.  C++ doesn't provide any way to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Provide me with your code to better understand your question?
else if you want to write to a file then you need to inlcude header file for that which is fstream
And the write this in main function

```
fstream myfile;


string myString;


getline(cin,myString);


char data[50];




myfile.open ("example.txt");


myfile << myString;


myfile.close();


return 0;
```